# GetBlockHtml, getChildHtml by name or alias - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks, frontend, local.xml

A small reminder to be sure, If I'm not mistaken;

- When an alias is declared in a `child block`, we called it by the **alias** instead of the name.
- When an alias is declared in a `block`, we called it by the **name** instead of the alias.

Here I call my child in `catalog/product/list.phtml` like this :

`<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('my.test'); ?> //it works.`

`<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('testoo'); ?> ///it doesn't work, it's logic.`

`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('my.test'); ?> //it doesn't work, it's logic.`

`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('testoo'); ?> //it doesn't work ?.`

```
<catalog_category_view>
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
            <block type="core/template" name="my.test" as="testoo" template="page/test/itest.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_view>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are little mess, that's why you confuse. So lets dive what happened actually here.

Open **app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php**, this is the master block class. So when you call

```
echo $this->getBlockHtml('my.test')
```

Open this method and see what happened.

```
/**
 * Retrieve block html
 *
 * @param   string $name
 * @return  string
 */
public function getBlockHtml($name)
{
    if (!($layout = $this->getLayout()) && !($layout = $this->getAction()->getLayout())) {
        return '';
    }
    if (!($block = $layout->getBlock($name))) {
        return '';
    }
    return $block->toHtml();
}
```

It's create a block object using 'name' attribute. So it's only work if you call with actual name attribute from layout xml.

Now what's happened when you call

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('my.test');
```

Lets check actual method

```
/**
 * Retrieve child block HTML
 *
 * @param   string $name
 * @param   boolean $useCache
 * @param   boolean $sorted
 * @return  string
 */
public function getChildHtml($name = '', $useCache = true, $sorted = false)
{
    if ($name === '') {
        if ($sorted) {
            $children = array();
            foreach ($this->getSortedChildren() as $childName) {
                $children[$childName] = $this->getLayout()->getBlock($childName);
            }
        } else {
            $children = $this->getChild();
        }
        $out = '';
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            $out .= $this->_getChildHtml($child->getBlockAlias(), $useCache);
        }
        return $out;
    } else {
        return $this->_getChildHtml($name, $useCache);
    }
}
```

So child class always use 'as' attributes for creating block object and it's return only child block not itself.

In your case your block has no child class that's why `echo $this->getChildHtml('testoo')` code not working.

**[Update]**

So when you call `echo $this->getChildHtml('testoo')` open this method.

```
/**
 * Retrieve child block HTML
 *
 * @param   string $name
 * @param   boolean $useCache
 * @return  string
 */
protected function _getChildHtml($name, $useCache = true)
{
    if ($useCache && isset($this->_childrenHtmlCache[$name])) {
        return $this->_childrenHtmlCache[$name];
    }

    $child = $this->getChild($name);

    if (!$child) {
        $html = '';
    } else {
        $this->_beforeChildToHtml($name, $child);
        $html = $child->toHtml();
    }

    $this->_childrenHtmlCache[$name] = $html;
    return $html;
}
```

Actually all children are set by **public function setChild($alias, $block)** method.

If layout config looks like:

```
<catalog_category_view>
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
            <block type="core/template" name="my.test" as="testoo" template="test/itest.phtml">
                <block type="core/template" name="my.test.child" as="testoo.child" template="test/childtest.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_view>
```

Now you can use following code in list.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('my.test'); ?>
```

And inside **test/itest.phtml**

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('testoo.child'); ?>
```

Comment: Why my block have no child ? `name="product_list"` is my block who display `list.phtml` and `name="my.test"` is his child ! i declared it like this in my `local.xml` like you can see it in my question

Comment: You told that `getChildHtml` always use `us` for creating block object, i can't see it in `public function getChildHtml`, he use well `$name` as paramater

Comment: Did you check $out .= $this->_getChildHtml($child->getBlockAlias(), $useCache); and $this->_getChildHtml($name, $useCache) line?

Comment: Check updated answer.

Comment: Yes, i understand now why `getChildHtml()` always use `us` for creating block object, but i didn't understand why my child doesn't work and the yours works, logically when we put some bock and insid another block, this another block becomes a child of the first one